# FIX CHECKSUM error on uploading artifact to artifactory

Tags: artifactory

Hellow I am getting error like below when I upload any artifact to Artifactory

[image]

The curl command is below:

```
CHECKSUM_md5sum=$(md5sum 3.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')CHECKSUM_sha1=$(sha1sum 3.txt | awk '{ print $1 }') CHECKSUM_sha256=$(sha256sum 3.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')  curl   -H "X-Checksum-md5sum:$CHECKSUM_md5sum" -H "X-Checksum-Sha1:$CHECKSUM_sha1" -H "X-Checksum-Sha256:$CHECKSUM_sha256" -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -v -X PUT https://tectcompany/artifactory/my-test-repo/3.txt
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend referring to this [JFrog KB Article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-are-client-checksum-server-checksum-and-checksum-policy-in-local-repositories/) on checksum for more insights.